# execute program as lsa

Tags: vb6, execute, lsa

I'm developing a program in windows (something like client & server) and I want to run server as LSA(local system account).but I don't know how?
**Note**: I'm writing my program in VB6 but I'm familiar with C#,C++ and C. So if your code is in any of these languages, I would be appreciate putting your code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options that come to mind. [This article](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1288/how-to-run-applications-in-the-local-system-account-lsa/) covers some of them.

Other things you could do is to add your app to the system startup process (via the MSCONFIG.exe app - "Start -> Run -> msconfig -> Startup" tab, or something like that).

Another way may be to setup your app so it can be installed as a service. You can configure any service to run under any arbitrary account on the machine, or via an account on your domain, if you're on a domain.

Another resource that looks like it might work for you is [this article](http://www.vbrad.com/article.aspx?id=92), which describes in more specifics, how to create a service from a VB6 app.

Comment: Thanks for answer but I should do it automatically.

Comment: The account under which an app, service, etc. runs is a function of when/where it's launched (via a service, system startup, etc.). I could be incorrect, but I don't think there is an "automatic" way to do this. You have to tell the system, somehow, that you want it to run as LSA, otherwise it will run under the currently logged in user account. There's certainly no way to run an app as the system account programatically - that would violate the UAC/security controls in Windows (assuming Vista/Win7). Allowing a program to grant **itself** access to run as the system = big no-no in security.

Comment: Thanks again. I meant NOT manually by the word "automatically". I think the best way is using service:)